# retrieving data from multiple table sequentially using foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have three tables connected through foreign key.
Here is what it looks like.

```
 Table A[a_id,project name]
 Table B[b_id,a_id,file name....]
 Table C[c_id,b_id,file data]
```

How can I retrieve the info from table C( contain file data) which references table B's three row(there are three files related to one project) which again references Table A's one row(project detail).

Comment: Try joining them. Search for the SQL JOIN keyword. It connects tables by matching values in rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For joining all three tables.

```
SELECT * FROM tableC
JOIN tableB ON tableB.b_id=tableC.b_id
JOIN tableA ON tableA.a_id=tableB.a_id
WHERE tableA.a_id=1 //Your project ID
```

You can also apply join for specific conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM tableC
JOIN tableB ON tableB.b_id=tableC.b_id AND tableB.b_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

select TableA.ProjectName, TableB.FileName, TableC.FileData
from TableC
Inner join TableB
On TableC.b_id = TableC.b_id
Inner Join TableA
On TableA.a_id = TableB.a_id

Comment: Hi In second line it should be TableB.b_id=TableC.b_id Now it works thanks